# I want to use a class component on the anoher file in react js but without server?

Tags: reactjs

I work on a small project and i want to implement the react in our projects but i don't want to use a node server. i already implemented a react js in my project without using node  but i face a problem that i want to import the react component in my App.js file and if i try to use import or require it generate the error and i don't know how  to fix this error.  here is my app.js file

my App.js file and i want to use a  product class in the same file

```
    function App(){
      return(
      <div>
        <Products name="@luispagarcia on Dev.to!"/>
      </div>
      )
    }
   ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

my another file is Product.js with a class component and i want to use this component in the app.js file 
Note:- i'm not using a node server so import keywards is not working

```
    class Products extends React.Component { 

    componentWillMount(){ 
     alert();
    }
        render() { 
            return (
            <div className="shopping-list">
            <h1>Shopping List for {this.props.name}</h1>
              <ul>
                <li>Instagram</li>
                <li>WhatsApp</li>
                <li>Oculus</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          );
          } 
        }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: App.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined thats a error in console

Comment: Post your error stack here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should follow your product import path and then be sure export default your class name

```
import Products from 'Your path';
function App(){
      return(
      <div>
        <Products name="@luispagarcia on Dev.to!"/>
      </div>
      )
    }
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

class Products extends React.Component { 
        render() { 
            return (
            <div className="shopping-list">
            <h1>Shopping List for {this.props.name}</h1>
              <ul>
                <li>Instagram</li>
                <li>WhatsApp</li>
                <li>Oculus</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          );
          } 
        }
export default Products
```

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible to run a React app without a production node server. So there's no effect this to your problem. You should export default class into your Products component(Products.js) and import products component into 'App.js'. 
Importing and exporting modules syntax changed completely between **ES5** and **ES6** syntax. 
EX:

```
   Export a module in ES5: module.exports = Products;
   Export a module in ES6: export default Products;

   Importing a module changed in ES5:  var myModule = require('./Products');   
   Importing a module changed in ES6:  import myModule from './Products';
```

So you should export & import modules according to the above details.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Products from 'Your Products component path here';
function App(){
  return(
  <div>
    <Products name="@luispagarcia on Dev.to!"/>
  </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

**Products.js**

```
import React from 'react';
class Products extends React.Component { 

componentWillMount(){ 
 alert();
}
    render() { 
        return (
        <div className="shopping-list">
        <h1>Shopping List for {this.props.name}</h1>
          <ul>
            <li>Instagram</li>
            <li>WhatsApp</li>
            <li>Oculus</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
      } 
    }

 export default Products;
```